# Ploting 3D graph in Racket

Tags: plot, lisp, racket

I am trying to plot a 3D graph using Racket and Dr. Racket.

I am using the library [plot](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/) and  I have been successful in many graphs, like:

```
#lang racket

(require plot)

(plot3d (surface3d (lambda (x y) (* x y (+ 1 (- x) (- y)))) (- 2) 2 (- 2) 2))

(plot3d (surface3d (lambda (x y) (* (sin y) x)) (- 1) 1 (- 5) 5))

(plot3d (surface3d (lambda (x y) (+ 4 (expt x 3) (expt y 3) (* -3 x y))) (- 2) 2 (- 2) 2))
```

However, when I try to graph the classical example of a line in 2D "y = x" but in 3D:

```
(plot3d (surface3d (lambda (x y) (+ x (- y)))
         10 10 10 10))
```

The program becomes an infinite script.

Maybe my math is wrong.

The line y=x in 2D would be  f(x,y)= x - y in 3D?

I would like to see y=x in 3D, that's what I want. How can I solve this?

Comment: Your program runs fine for me, but your plot bounds are all `10`, so there’s nothing to render. If I change them to `0 10 0 10`, I see the plane `z = x - y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to draw lines:

```
#lang racket
(require plot)

(define (line-through p q)
  (match* (p q)
    [((list px py pz) (list qx qy qz))
     (λ (t)
       (vector (+ px (* t (- qx px)))
               (+ py (* t (- qy py)))
               (+ pz (* t (- qz pz)))))]))

(plot3d (parametric3d (line-through '(1 1 1) '(1 2 3))
                      -1e6 1e6))
```

If you want to draw the solution set to the equation `y=z` (which is a plane)
you can do this:

```
(plot3d (list (surface3d (λ (x y) (- x y))))
        #:x-min -10 #:x-max 10
        #:y-min -10 #:y-max 10
        #:z-min -10 #:z-max 10)
```